# Can't Saving HighScore using NSUserDefaults in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am making game by Cocos2d and SpriteBuilder. I have problem :( . 
EX :The first time my score is 8, the high score is 8. Then, I retry game, my score > 8, when I'm die ==> bug show :(

My source with highscore:

```
    NSNumber *highScore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"_highscore"];
    if (self.score > [highScore intValue]) {
        // new highscore
        highScore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.score];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:@"_highscore"];--->BUG

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by BUG? does it crash? does it not update the highscore?

Comment: I think it crash :( 
The first time I run the program in Xcode , update new highScore is okay. Then I retry game and have score > highScore    ----> BUG                                      

**** [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:highScore forKey:@"_highscore"];

Comment: you *think* it crashes? Does it or does it not? If it does post the crash message and log.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to get/set the highscore. It's working in released games. Hope it helps!

```
+(void)setNewHighScore:(int)score{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"GameNameHighScore"];
}

+(int)getHighScore{
    int highScore = 0;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    highScore = [[defaults valueForKey:@"GameNameHighScore"] intValue];
    return highScore;
}
```